# Counting Answers By day mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table called myTable.

With the following fields

ID
Date_Done
Successful    ('Yes', 'No', Null)
Total_Cost

I know I can get a per day count by using

```
SELECT Date_Done, COUNT(*) FROM myTable Group By Date_Done;
```

What I want is a count of the number of  'Yes" andsers in Successful by day.

What does that SQL look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Date_Done, SUM(Successful = 'Yes')
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Date_Done
```

Comment: How is this any better than `WHERE Successful='Yes'`?

Comment: leaves open the possibility of adding a `sum(successful = 'no')` to split the count.

Comment: Thanks Mark.   You answered so fast that I cant accept the answer fro 8 more minutes.....

Comment: That doesn't split the count, it just switches the type of count being done. It also completely ignores indexes, forcing a row scan.

Answer (score 2):

A straight-up sum:

```
SELECT Date_Done, COUNT(*) AS Successful_Count
  FROM myTable
  WHERE Successful='Yes'
  GROUP BY Date_Done
```

If you have an index on `Date_Done, Successful` this will usually be quite fast.

A sum where you want to break out individual status codes:

```
SELECT Date_Done, Successful, COUNT(*) AS Type_Count
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY Date_Done, Successful
```

Once again an index here will improve performance considerably.

Comment: An index on `(Successful, Date_Done)` will be better.

Comment: That wouldn't help with a `COUNT(*) GROUP BY Date_Done` query, though.

Comment: And I guess you meant to remove the `WHERE` from the 2nd query.